# Reporting engines in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, birt

is there anything different between Formula One and Birt Reporting Engines? I searched on google and some sites say that Birt is the newer version of Formula One Engine. I also found something called ERD? Is it also a reporting engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula One and BIRT have almost nothing to do with each other.

Formula One was a previous Java based spreadsheet reporting product that was bought by Actuate, and turned into the eSpreadsheet product line, and later turned into the BIRT Spreadsheet product line. Outside of the marketing name, the technology itself has nothing to do with the BIRT platform.

BIRT is a Java based reporting engine thats main focus is web based reporting. It has several API's under its umbrella (Report Engine API, Design Engine API, and Chart Engine API) that several reporting products are built on top of (BIRT Report Designer, BIRT 360 Dashboard, Interactive Viewer, Business REports Studio). The BIRT Engine and Eclipse based designer are free, open source products, and the BIRT API's are free to integrate into your product.

ERD is Actuates legacy reporting platform thats main focus was print based reporting. It used a banded paradigm similar to Crystal Reports. It was implemented using C/C++, and leveraged a licensed version of Visual Basic for its report designs. It is still actively supported by Actuate, however BIRT is their main focus. It has no integration points outside of the web services that are provided by iServer.